# How to connect multiple classes and all around understanding Java

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I just started coding in Java and my professor is not the best and teaching it. We were assigned a program that I vaguely understand. I'd really like to understand how it works and how I should look at the problem. Ex. how do I create a department, then store professors in it, leave and make more departments and such, then come back and retrieve the professors from other departments. I don't understand how I am supposed to do that in Java. If anyone could help a beginner out that would be great. Thanks.

**Picture of my assignment:**

[image: Picture of my assignment]

Comment: This question is too broad and it's unclear what you are struggling with. If anything it sounds like you should consult a good Java tutorial

Comment: I'd read the suggested text that pairs with your course and/or seek help from fellow classmates and/or study sessions.

Comment: Hey Connor, welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to read up on [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then come back and revisit yours. As is, your question will most likely be flagged as too broad, as there is no specific question. I suggest you read up on the basics of Java and [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), then try your best at solving the task, then ask about the specific issues you're running into.

Comment: It sounds like you're struggling with Object Oriented Programming, rather than Java itself (to be fair, Java is often someone's first introduction to that concept). I suggest looking through this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming, then either discussing it with your classmates or going to office hours.

Comment: Here is a starting point for you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/

Answer (score 0):

A Java class is just a template for a structure with some properties and some methods. An instance of such a class would be called an object. One of those properties may reference other objects, like this:

```
class Department{
  Set<Professor> profs= new HashSet<>();
}

class Professor{
}
```

Now, if you want to make two (unnamed) Departments and add some (unnamed) Professors to it, you would add:

```
Department[] aDep= new Department[new Department(), new Department()];
aDep[0].profs.add(new Professor());
aDep[1].profs.add(new Professor());
aDep[1].profs.add(new Professor());
```

After this, the first Department would have one Professor, the second two.